# CakePHP custom route w/ %20 in url want to replace w/ "-" not sure how to make this happen in the route

Tags: php, url, cakephp, router

**My link:**

```
echo $link->link($planDetailsByCompany['PlanDetail']['name'],
    array('controller' => 'plan_details', 'action' => 'view_benefit_schedule',
    'id' => $planDetailsByCompany['PlanDetail']['id'],
    'slug' =>  $planDetailsByCompany['PlanDetail']['name']));
```

**My custom route:**

```
Router::connect('/pd/:id-:slug',
    array('controller' => 'plan_details', 'action' => 'view_benefit_schedule'),
    array('pass' => array('id', 'slug'),
    'id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

**My url is displaying like so:**

```
..pd/44-Primary%20Indemnity
```

I cannot determine how to remove the %20 and replace it with a  "-". There is a space in the company name that is causing this. Is this possible within the CakePHP router functionality? If so, how? Or another method.

Answer (score 0):

Geeze.. I just solved this!

In my link above, replace the 'slug' line with:

```
...'slug' =>  Inflector::slug($planDetailsByCompany['PlanDetail']['name'])...
```

The Inflector handles the spaces in the url. And my result url is:

```
...pd/44-Primary_Indemnity
```

Comment: but this might only work in this/your case. if you use real slugs, there will be no id in the url neccessary. to use real slug you need a extra unique DB field for it and save the slug there (with Inflector::slug)

Comment: http://42pixels.com/blog/slugs-ugly-bugs-pretty-urls   You do *NOT* need to have a db field to do slug lookups. This method uses custom routing and params to do slug type urls. Otherwise, you need to make certain your PlanDetail.name value is completely unique - if not then your slug could possibly match 2 id's using the Inflector::slug on the field like you are doing.

Comment: In addition to my solution, the Inflector::slug() takes an additional parameter (defaults to underscore), and I wanted dashes, so in the second argument, just add the separator you want like: ['PlanDetail']['name'],'-') then dashes replace the default underscore.